# Add an XML node before a closing node

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I need to add my XML tree before a closing node, I just can't seem to find the solution.The sample below in the red block just needs to move above the `</quiz>` node.

[image]

This is my XML code done in PHP which creates the above section of XML in the red block.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('quiz.xml');


$questionLoad = $xml->addChild('question');
$textQue = $questionLoad->addChild('text', $que);
$optionNode = $questionLoad->addChild('option');
$ans1 = $optionNode->addChild('text', $answer1);
$score = $optionNode->addChild('score', $score1);
$explain = $optionNode->addChild('explanation');
$expl1 = $explain->addChild('text', $explanation1);

$xml->asXML('quiz.xml');
```

Comment: _“The sample below in the red block just needs to move above the `</quiz>` node.”_ – there is no such thing as a “closing _node_”, only a closing _tag_. If you want to append an element as the last child element of an existing node, then use appendChild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given input `quiz.xml` with the contents of

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<quizzes>
    <quiz>
        <question>
            <text>Choose the correct word for hot + est</text>
            <option>
                <text>hottest</text>
                <score>5</score>
                <explanation>
                    <text>Correct!</text>
                </explanation>
            </option>
            <option>
                <text>hotestt</text>
                <score>0</score>
                <explanation>
                    <text>Incorrect!</text>
                </explanation>
            </option>
            <option>
                <text>hotest</text>
                <score>0</score>
                <explanation>
                    <text>Incorrect!</text>
                </explanation>
            </option>
        </question>
    </quiz>
</quizzes>
```

the following PHP adapted from your code

```
<?php

$que = 'fsa';
$answer1 = 'cs';
$score1 = 5;
$explanation1 = 'hgfhfg';

$xml = simplexml_load_file('quiz.xml');

$questionLoad = $xml->children()[0]->addChild('question');
$textQue = $questionLoad->addChild('text', $que);
$optionNode = $questionLoad->addChild('option');
$ans1 = $optionNode->addChild('text', $answer1);
$score = $optionNode->addChild('score', $score1);
$explain = $optionNode->addChild('explanation');
$expl1 = $explain->addChild('text', $explanation1);

$xml->asXML('quiz.xml');
```

produces the wanted result `quiz.xml` of

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<quizzes>
    <quiz>
        <question>
            <text>Choose the correct word for hot + est</text>
            <option>
                <text>hottest</text>
                <score>5</score>
                <explanation>
                    <text>Correct!</text>
                </explanation>
            </option>
            <option>
                <text>hotestt</text>
                <score>0</score>
                <explanation>
                    <text>Incorrect!</text>
                </explanation>
            </option>
            <option>
                <text>hotest</text>
                <score>0</score>
                <explanation>
                    <text>Incorrect!</text>
                </explanation>
            </option>
        </question>
    <question><text>fsa</text><option><text>cs</text><score>5</score><explanation><text>hgfhfg</text></explanation></option></question></quiz>
</quizzes>
```

Answer (score 0):

in above code you are loading a xml and simple adding a node, which will always be added at the end of file.

try using append instead of add for ex :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML("<root/>");
$f = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$f->appendXML("<foo>text</foo><bar>text2</bar>");
$doc->documentElement->appendChild($f);
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

For reference only.